# Any VNC viewer support zooming?

Tags: macos, vnc

Is there any VNC viewer that allows you to zoom out?

The desktop computer that I VNC into has a resolution that's considerably larger than the laptop I'm viewing with.  The scroll bars in Chicken of the VNC are way too unwieldy to use effectively, and the falloff zoom in JollyFastVNC is a little hot and requires you to awkwardly move to the edge and back.

I wish I could just zoom out, pan around, and zoom in when needed almost like photoshop.  Any viewer have features like this?  OSX is preferred but I'd be interested in any platform.

Comment: I wish we could do pinch to zoom and drag on touchscreens

Answer (score 3):

- Please try this TightVNC: go here http://www.tightvnc.com/intro.php

Comment: RealVNC supports this as well https://www.realvnc.com/

Comment: gvncviewer defaults to a zoomed display

Answer (score 2):

http://www.realvnc.com/cgi-bin/download.cgi

The viewer is free.

Answer (score 2):

OS X's built-in `Screen Sharing.app` (located in /System/Library/CoreServices in 10.6) is light on features, but it's pretty fast, totally free, integrated with the operating system already, and has your fit-to-window option. Here is Screen Sharing connected to a remote host running at 1920x1080 screen resolution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've not used VNC regularly for a long time, but I seem to remember that [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/) had a fit-to-screen option.  UltraVNC has a lot more options than any other version of VNC that I have used.

Answer (score 1):

[Jolly's Fast VNC](http://www.jinx.de/JollysFastVNC.html) has a "fish eye" type zoom mode called SmartZoom that lets you fit more resolution from a remote machine on a smaller screen. It's a little weird the first time you use it, but it starts to make sense after a while and it's definitely better than scaling the resolution down or having to put up with scroll bars in to navigate the full, remote desktop.

The download version is free but buying it is encouraged. It's available via [the App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/id406781941) as well as direct download.

Of all the OS X VNC programs it's the one I've come to like. The SmartZoom works well once you get the hang of it and the UI and features are top notch, very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Jump Desktop](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jump-desktop-remote-desktop/id524141863?ls=1&mt=12).

It lets you use pinch gestures on the trackpad to quickly zoom in and out of the remote screen.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I have VNC viewer and, when the program is open, I right click at the top of it, go to options, and select 'scale to window size.'